# Get the user selected value from Angular Material's mat-calendar or rendering a mat-datepicker in a component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was just wanting to ask if anyone had any experience with working with the `<mat-calendar>` from Angular Material? I want a calendar component nested in my html template rather than displayed in a Popup / Modal when clicking a button or some kind of toggle. The [Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) doesn't seem to support this (unless I missed it) so I thought that I could add a `mat-calendar` to my form, then knowing there is a `userSelected` output I could "listen" for that and run a method to get the selected value...

In my HTML...

```
<div>
    Select a day:
    <mat-calendar #myDate (userSelection)="getChangedValue($event)"></mat-calendar>
<div>
```

In my component

```
getChangedValue(e)  {
    console.log(e); // this is always "undefined"
  }
```

However on looking through the `mat-calendar` code I can see the output "userSelection" returns void so I can't get the selected value there and the rendered calendar aesthetically isn't great and will require some extensive CSS work. I was just curious to know if anyone has worked on this before and could shed some light on how I can get the selected value (i.e. the selected date) from the mat-calendar - this may save me some time whilst I go through the documentation. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From studying the code of the Angualar Material repository the selected date is exposed using an output called `selectedChange`. I can get the date using this, for example:

```
<mat-calendar #myDate (selectedChange)="getChangedValue($event)"></mat-calendar>
```